# react-dnd: how to drop DragSource into native input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I'd like to have a list of react components which are wrapped with `DragSource` from 'react-dnd'.

It is used in a couple of places with `DropTarget` successfully.
The issue is related to the ability to drop into a browser's native input (`<input type="text" />` or `<textarea />`).

I couldn't find any examples of how to implement this.

Is it actually possible?
I'd like to have a similar to a native behavior: dropping into a specific cursor's position at least.

How to achieve this? 
Should an input be wrapped into a React's component wrapped into `DropTarget` with custom calculation of a cursor position.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you got any solutions?

Comment: @user257980 I had to implement calculation of a cursor position which is called in a drop() method.